# Any open source release management system like codeplex or sourceforge?

Tags: release-management

does any one knows any open source release management system could be hosted on own server? something like codeplex or sourcefoge

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) or [GForge](http://gforge.org/gf/).

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) ?

Comment: does Trac support "download" management? just wondering. didn't get this feature when using their demo site

Comment: I don't think so. Most of the people who are using it create a download page in their trac wiki.

Answer (score 1):

[Savane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Savannah#Savane), which is forked off of what SourceForge uses and is used by [GNU Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/launchpad), which handles bugs/issues, source code, and so forth.  However, it is not easy to install (well, it may have gotten better, but it did not used to be easy to install) and if you wanted to run a public version on the Internet, you would need to do some serious re-branding of it.

Comment: does LaunchPad support "Download" management? wondering why it is not supported in some release management software

Comment: What do you mean by "'download' management", exactly?  You can roll releases, and upload the tarballs/installers/etc along with signatures and it will track how many of what downloads are completed...

Answer (score 0):

[fusion forge](https://fusionforge.org/)